# PHP array won't store a variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I am working on a website, and while coding, I came across a strange bug.

I am storing MySQL query results in an array, then call a JavaScript function with the stored data. The array originally contained 9 items: 8 with tinyint(4) type (in the database - I don't know if it could be useful), and one with int(11). Later, I realized I have to pass a String with them, too, so I included a Varchar(40) type item.

Here is the problem. Until this point, the code runs without any error - I can pass the variables, use them in the JS code and display them on the site. As soon as I include the string, the site crashes (nothing is displayed).

Here is the code:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql7.000webhost.com","a2248489_admin","SQL123DevAdmin","a2248489_players");
$con2=mysqli_connect("mysql7.000webhost.com","a2248489_admin","SQL123DevAdmin","a2248489_players");

// Check connection
$troopArray = array(array()); 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  ID, Name FROM Player");

$counter = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$troops = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Troops WHERE ID = '" . $row['ID'] . "' ");
while($sor = mysqli_fetch_array($troops)) {
    $troopArray[$counter][0] = $sor['archerLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][1] = $sor['giantLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][2] = $sor['wizardLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][3] = $sor['balloonLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][4] = $sor['dragonLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][5] = $sor['minionLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][6] = $sor['hogLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][7] = $sor['golemLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][8] = $sor['witchLvl'];

    $troopArray[$counter][9] = $row['ID'];

    $troopArray[$counter][10] = $row['Name'];
    $counter++;

  }
}

//------------------Writing the name into a new DIV------------------------
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var nameButton = document.createElement("input");';
echo 'nameButton.setAttribute("type","button");';
echo 'nameButton.setAttribute("value","' . $row['Name'] . '");';
echo 'nameButton.setAttribute("name","' . $row['ID'] . '");';
echo 'nameButton.style.backgroundImage="url(\"images/login_button/button_name.png\")";';
echo 'nameButton.style.marginLeft = "5px";';
echo 'nameButton.style.marginTop = "0px";';
echo 'nameButton.style.height="60px";';
echo 'nameButton.style.width="200px";';
echo 'nameButton.style.border ="none";';
echo 'nameButton.style.backgroundColor ="transparent";';
echo 'nameButton.style.fontWeight="900";';
echo 'nameButton.style.paddingLeft="50px";';
echo 'nameButton.style.textAlign="left";';
echo 'nameButton.onclick = function() 
                                    {

                                        TableDraw(' . $troopArray[0][0] . ',' . $troopArray[0][1] . ',' . $troopArray[0][2] . ',' . $troopArray[0][3] . ',' . $troopArray[0][4] . ',' . $troopArray[0][5] . ',' . $troopArray[0][6] . ',' . $troopArray[0][7] . ',' . $troopArray[0][8] . ',' . $troopArray[0][9] . ',' . $troopArray[0][10] . ');

                                    };';
echo 'document.body.appendChild(nameButton);';
echo '</script>';
echo '<br>';

 ?>
```

Everything's OK until `$troopArray[$counter][10] = $row['Name'];`, I even use it later on when I set it as a button's text. If I change 'Name' into 'ID', the code runs.

As far as I know, I can store any type of variables in a PHP array, because it's not truly an array. But why I can't seem to store a string among the integers?

Comment: Is your column called `name` instead of `Name` by any chance?

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I later use it in the same format in this line: `echo 'nameButton.setAttribute("value","' . $row['Name'] . '");';`, and it's working (the button's text is correct).

Comment: maybe your array is fixed length to 10? Can't remember if PHP arrays were fixed length

Comment: (Sidenote) If that's your full code or close to, you're missing a closing brace `}` other than that, I don't know what the problem could be. Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything more.

Comment: By the way, you had `$troopArray[$counter][10] = $row['Name'];` shouldn't that be `$troopArray[$counter][10] = $sor['Name'];`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- likely not, he's selecting `Name` from the player table, so he's referring `$row`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$row` is from the outer loop set.

Comment: @Julian OP's using the `$row` var for `$row['ID']` so I can't say for sure. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Fred -ii- 'Name' is from another query, the same as 'ID'.

Comment: Ok, the only thing I can see that's seems out of whack are the two different DB variables `$con` and `$con2`, now it's official, I'm out of ideas lol or that both your tables have `Name` in there or other same column names, since you're select all for 2nd table.

Comment: There is still no end of first loop

Comment: You are assigning the character name into a javascript array without quotes around it.

Comment: Your while loop `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` is missing a closing brace, just [`as I said earlier.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532579/php-array-wont-store-a-variable#comment37988268_24532579)

Comment: @Kickstart I don't know what to say. Thank you, that was the problem. I added the quotes and it's working.

Comment: Had you posted full code from the beginning, all of this could've been avoided. @Kickstart should put in an answer and close this fiasco.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error in your code, but one thing is strange for me:

```
$troopArray = array(array());
```

You should change this line simple into:

```
$troopArray = array();
```

and check if the problem still occurs

One extra thing is that your `$counter` is always 0. It doesn't cause problem but maybe you want also to increment it before end of loop?

**EDIT**

If problem still occurs you should show us the whole loop code (now it finishes after first loop and maybe somewhere later you change something in your `$row` variable

Comment: Yeah, those two `array()` are also strange to me.

Comment: No. As you can see, `$troopArray` is an array of arrays, as the code references an array using `$troopArray[$counter]`. I'm a bit confused, 'cause `$counter` never gets increased

Comment: @Julian I know, but I haven't seen such construct. Even if array has 3 dimensions you simple always initialize array using `$array = array();` as far as I know

Comment: No. PHP initializes an array as you set an element of it. So because of PHP's fail safeness, he don't need's to initialize an array at all. This would also work perfectly: `$troopArray; $troopArray[0]['a'] = "b";`.

Comment: `$counter` gets increased as soon as the `while($sor = mysqli_fetch_array($troops)) {}` cycle is over. I didn't included because it's not relevant.

Comment: @benedekadam: It **IS** relevant as you see! Things like this are the likeliest issue in coding, I think.

Comment: @benedekadam show the whole code of your loops

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I included the full PHP code.

Comment: @benedekadam The code is incomplete. You never end first loop - no `}` character anywhere

Comment: +1 for your time and effort. OP **should** have posted full code from the start. I for one am quite annoyed at OP's original post.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an issue, but can it be recoded to use a JOIN and save the loop inside a loop? Assuming that they are both on the same database

```
$troopArray = array();
$counter = 0;
$sql = "SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, b.archerLvl, b.giantLvl, b.wizardLvl, b.balloonLvl, b.dragonLvl, b.minionLvl, b.hogLvl, b.golemLvl, b.witchLvl
        FROM Player a
        INNER JOIN Troops b
        ON a.ID = b.ID";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $troopArray[$counter] = array();
    $troopArray[$counter][0] = $row['archerLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][1] = $row['giantLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][2] = $row['wizardLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][3] = $row['balloonLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][4] = $row['dragonLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][5] = $row['minionLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][6] = $row['hogLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][7] = $row['golemLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][8] = $row['witchLvl'];
    $troopArray[$counter][9] = $row['ID'];
    $troopArray[$counter][10] = $row['Name'];
    $counter++;
}
```

If you do this you can try doing a print_r of each $row and also a print_r of $troopArray when it has been populated and check that they look right.

As an aside, does the first Name happen to be a number?

EDIT - problem appears to be where you assign the values from this array into a javascript array. You have assigned it into the javascript array without surrounding quotes. This is probably resulting in javascript trying to find a variable called the value of Name to assign into the array.

Comment: +1 good catch. OP should've posted full code from the beginning and easily avoid all of this wasted time for everybody.